# how to make a single line text used as a glyph(mac develop)

Tags: macos

Effect like the mac mail app,this image is a screenshot
[image: Effect like the mac mail app,this image is a screenshot]

1. how can i get effect like that. I try the cocoa text system,and don't find some useful things.
2. and I use the nstextattachment with textatttachmentcell initImageCell,obtain some effect like that,but it is not good,it is not very nature.

please some one give directions to me.

Answer (score 0):

Those objects are not glyphs, they are controls, such as a subclass of a button. Custom controls have a drawing routine, which you override to draw a blue rectangle with round corners (a bezier path is the most flexible way to do so), then you draw the text (including the caret character) centered in the blue rectangle. Finally, handle the mouse events to do what you need to do when the control is clicked, such as popping up a menu in the right location.

Comment: if use nsview example controls,there is a problem that the cursor will be cover.it is not like a character that show nature.

Comment: I think the blue chunk is some thing like a glyph.I use attachment with attachmentcell(initImageCell) and get some  similar effect, but it looks not nature.